# How to check if a number exists in a specified digit of an integer ( C# )

Tags: c#, integer

I want to generally verify if a number/character exists within a specified index of an int value.

Here is pseudocode of what I want

```
        if (octet[1].Exists){
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }

        // receiving int octet = 103 will return true.
        // receiving int octet = 7 will return false.
```

Is there a function that already does this, or do you have to make one on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a string then check the length?

```
var str = octet.ToString();
return str.Length >= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a function like this, but you can write your own.
In instance:

```
var func = (int octet, int index) => (octet / (int)(Math.Pow(10, index)) != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a System.Linq binding for this. Here is an example:

```
octet.ToString().Contains(n);
```

Where `n` is the digit you're looking for in string or char form. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the int to a string and check if the number you are looking is equal to expected position.

```
  var number = 12345;
            if(number.ToString().IndexOf('2') == 1)//check if the value 2 is on the second position of the array
            {
                Console.WriteLine("yes");
            }
```